# How do I plot multiple files in a single graph?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming. This program I have here is to read and plot 'n' files of xvg format to compare the graphs.
I want the program to be able to let me add as many xvg files as I want and plot them all in a single graph(each of different color) so that they can be compared.
I wrote the program and was able to plot the graph for only a single file at a time. Each file is opening up in a new window.

```js
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size':15})
root = Tk()
root.title("Graph plotter")
root.geometry("900x800")


def processxvg(filename):
    x, y = [], []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line[0] != "#" and line[0] != "@":
                cols = line.split()
                if len(cols) == 2:
                    x.append(float(cols[0]))
                    y.append(float(cols[1]))
    return x,y

def random_color():
    levels = range(32,256,32)
    return tuple(random.choice(levels) for _ in range(3))

def browsefunc():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pathlabel.config(text=filename)

def addbox():
    browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc)
    browsebutton.pack()


my_label = Label(root, text= "Browse the xvg file in the dir", font =("Ariel", "20") )
my_label.pack()



pathlabel = Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

def clicked1():
    (x, y) = processxvg(filename)
    f = plt.figure()
    f.set_figwidth(20)
    f.set_figheight(10)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.xlabel("Time (ns)", fontsize="35", labelpad=25)
    plt.ylabel("RMSD (nm)", fontsize="35", labelpad=25)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

add_files_button = Button(root, text ="Add files", command = addbox)
add_files_button.pack()

plotbutton = Button(root, text ="Plot", command = clicked1 )
plotbutton.pack(pady = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently creating a new figure object every time the `clicked1` function is called. The simplest solution would be to bring the figure creation outside of the function definition. I would also explicitly use the axis object to ensure everything plots on the same axis:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.set_xlabel("Time (ns)", fontsize="35", labelpad=25)
ax.set_ylabel("RMSD (nm)", fontsize="35", labelpad=25)
plt.ion()  # Enable interactive plotting

def clicked1():
    (x, y) = processxvg(filename)
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Ideally you would not use global variables, but instead pass ax as an argument to `clicked1`.